# How to derive $Exp(\phi) R = R Exp(R^T \phi)$ for SO(3)

Tags: lie-groups, rotations, matrix-exponential, kinematics

I am reading https://limhyungtae.github.io/2022-04-01-IMU-Preintegration-(Easy)-4.-Derivation-of-Preintegrated-IMU-Measurements/

And trying to work my way through it, I already asked some questions wrt right-jacobians but I am also stuck on how you derive $Exp(\phi) R = R Exp(R^T \phi)$ We are working on SO(3).

$\phi$ is the vector representing a rotation where $||\phi||_2$ is the angle. I believe it is implicitly put in skew-symmetric form.

Naively expanding the series defintion hasn't lead me anywhere

Comment: What is "$R$" for ?

Comment: It's a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation used in your question is confusing and is actually  hiding important details. What I think is going on here is that vector argument of exponential map is transformed into skew-symmetric matrix under the hood. Let me explain:

Let $v$ be a 3d vector, $[v]_×$ be a $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix (a.k.a. the "cross product" matrix) of veector $v$ and $R$ be a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix.

The skew-symmetric matrix $[v]_×$ belongs to the Lie algebra of the rotation group SO(3) so the expomential map $\exp([v]_×)$ gives a rotation matrix via Rodrigues formula.

The notation you're using is "wrong" in the sense thar you are applying the exponential map to a vector $v$ like $\exp(v)$. That doesn't make actual sense. But it seem the author you are following has stablished the following abuse of notation: $\exp(v) = \exp([v]_×)$.

The skew-symmetric matrices forms a vector space and rotations can be applied to them where the following identity holds:

$[R \ v]_× = R \ [v]_× \ R^T$

So the following relation holds:

$\exp([R \ v]_×) = \exp(R \ [v]_× \ R^T)$

But $\exp(R \ [v]_× \ R^T) = R \ \exp([v]_×) \ R^T$ as can be checked by expanding $\exp(R \ [v]_× \ R^T)$ using the Rodrigues formula, so:

$\exp([R \ v]_×) = R \ \exp([v]_×) \ R^T$

Then going back to your question, it is basically:

$\exp([v]_×) \ R = R \ \exp([R^T \ v]_×)$

Which can be rewrited as:

$R^T \ \exp([v]_×) \ R = \exp([R^T \ v]_×)$

Which clearly holds.

Comment: That first identity was what I missed, to prove it would it be a direct computation?

Comment: It follows from linearity of cross product: $R (v ×  w) = (R v) × (R w)$ which implies $R [v]_× = [R v]_× R$